# Why am I getting a key error every time I run 'exit' in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When prompted to enter the course number or enter exit to leave, I enter 'exit' and it kept giving me a key error. The intended outcome should be printing "Program terminated normally" but instead I got a key error.

```
instructor = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', \'CS103': 'Rich','NT110': 'Burke', 'CM241': 'Lee'}

room = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', \'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'} 

time = {'CS101': '8:00 a.m.', 'CS102': '9:00 a.m.', \'CS103': '10:00 a.m.', 'NT110': '11:00 a.m.', 'CM241': '1:00 p.m.'}
exit = 0

while exit != 1:

course = input("Enter the course number or enter exit to leave: ").upper()

print()

print("The course information for course # " + course + " is as follows:")
print('Room #: ', room[course])
print('Instructor: ', instructor[course])
print('Time: ', time[course])
if course.upper() == "exit":
    exit = 1
    print("Program terminated normally")
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly and paste the *full* error traceback.

Comment: Check the syntax highlighting above and see that there are 3 bad escaped quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems in the code.
1. The exit condition can be checked before in a `if` condition, then the rest of the logic in else. Right now the loop the loop runs once more after you type exit, causing the `KeyError`.
2. You should check `course.lower() == 'exit'` instead of `upper()`.
3. Unexpected backslashes in the code

Below code will work and has the fixes mentioned above

```
instructor = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich','NT110': 'Burke', 'CM241': 'Lee'}

room = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', 'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'}

time = {'CS101': '8:00 a.m.', 'CS102': '9:00 a.m.', 'CS103': '10:00 a.m.', 'NT110': '11:00 a.m.', 'CM241': '1:00 p.m.'}
exit = 0

while exit != 1:

    course = input("Enter the course number or enter exit to leave: ").upper()

    print()
    #lower instead of upper
    if course.lower() == "exit":
        exit = 1
        print("Program terminated normally")
    else:
        print("The course information for course # " + course + " is as follows:")
        print('Room #: ', room[course])
        print('Instructor: ', instructor[course])
        print('Time: ', time[course])
```

Output will look like

```
Enter the course number or enter exit to leave: CS101

The course information for course # CS101 is as follows:
Room #:  3004
Instructor:  Haynes
Time:  8:00 a.m.
Enter the course number or enter exit to leave: exit

Program terminated normally
```

Also you can use `sys.exit()` to exit your code instead of checking variable `exit` like so.

```
instructor = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich','NT110': 'Burke', 'CM241': 'Lee'}

room = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', 'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'}

time = {'CS101': '8:00 a.m.', 'CS102': '9:00 a.m.', 'CS103': '10:00 a.m.', 'NT110': '11:00 a.m.', 'CM241': '1:00 p.m.'}

import sys

while True:

    course = input("Enter the course number or enter exit to leave: ").upper()

    print()
    if course.lower() == "exit":
        print("Program terminated normally")
        #This will exit the code
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("The course information for course # " + course + " is as follows:")
        print('Room #: ', room[course])
        print('Instructor: ', instructor[course])
        print('Time: ', time[course])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue in your code with escaping keys when you create the dicts (`4501', \'CS103`), why do you need this backslash?

You're also missing an indent block for the while loop.

But, getting to the point: If you flow through your code after inputting "exit", you'll first go to:

```py
print("The course information for course # " + course + " is as follows:")
print('Room #: ', room[course])
print('Instructor: ', instructor[course])
print('Time: ', time[course])
```

You try to get the course attributes using `room[course]`, which throws KeyError if key isn't in the dicts, here course "exit" isn't a valid every in `room`.